# SQL creating a sproc to return data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

This is a really simple question that has me stumped.

All I'm wanting to do is try and return some data from a table in a sproc that I'm creating so I can use it in a SSRS report.

Here is my attempt thus far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsageStatistics (@DisplayName VARCHAR(305))
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT DisplayName 
FROM myTable 
WHERE DisplayName = @DisplayName
```

Right now I have an error telling me `Incorrect syntax near '@DisplayName'.` But I'm not sure what is wrong. My understanding of creating a variable with the @ symbol before it was that I was wanting to `pass in` parameters I want but what I'm trying to do is return the values.

Can someone please explain to me where I'm failing in my understanding of how sprocs work and how I can rectify this?

Comment: @juergend tried that, but still get the same error, I'll update my code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely missing an `END`.  Does this work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsageStatistics (
    @DisplayName VARCHAR(305)
) AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT DisplayName 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE DisplayName = @DisplayName;
END;
```

Notes:

- This stored procedure is non-sensical, because it returns either `NULL` or the input.
- You should consider using a function instead.  A scalar function would make sense in this case (assuming that only one row would normally be returned).

Comment: Thank you, that has stopped the error. This is my first time making a sproc and all I'm wanting to do is return the value of DisplayName from my table. I was looking around for examples and this seemed to be how to do it. I've zero idea about SQL functions

Answer (score 0):

```
-- =============================================
USE [YourDBName]
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsageStatistics 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @DisplayName varchar(20) 
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here

    SELECT DisplayName 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE DisplayName = @DisplayName 

    END
    GO
```